# Reason behind the crack in window glass

Tags: windows, glass

Please take a look at attached picture of my double hung window with double panel glass.

One night, I heard the glass breaking noise and when I checked in the morning I saw this crack on the inside panel of the glass. Outside panel is fine.

Outside temperature that night was -10 degree Celsius, and inside was around 19 degree Celsius.

Could this be due to temperature difference ?

[image]

Comment: Glass only cracks with different temps if it is a rapid change, very hot oven to an ice bath.  A defect in the glass or the window being too tight in the frame are the usual reasons, besides being hit.

Comment: If that was the case all my windows would be broken every winter.  -10C is quite pleasant relative to my typical winters. There was a flaw or some stress on the glass. Maybe revise to ask about repairs instead of a cause that's highly unlikely.

Comment: it actually could be because of the temp, but not how you think. When it's cold it gets dry, and when it's dry wood shrinks. The frame or studs around the window could have tightened up just enough for the forces to bee too much for the pane.

Comment: Anything's possible, but every Andersen 200 and 400 window is wood. They don't break even when it's -40F/C.

Comment: why do you want  to know whether it is caused by temperature difference?

Answer (score 1):

The fix depends on whether it is still under warranty. Some companies offer 5-10 years warranty, so check that.

If that does not work try your Home Owner insurance, since it is accidental they might pay

The reason is unknown and not relevant for fixing it, but it could be a invisible defect/crack in the glass, not the temperature difference since it is uniform and does not stress the glass to the breaking point

Comment: The reason might be important if the window is fitted too tight into the wood framing and cracked from house movement/settling.  Pets(birds, dogs/cats, kids) could be another reason, but OP does not mention having them.

Comment: @crip659 the reason will not fix the window unless the same mistake was made

Comment: Will prevent the window cracking again, if fixed.  OP probably thinking of just replacing the glass(maybe window) and calling it good.  This is a good plan if a rock was found.

Comment: @crip659 to help OP, do you know the required spacing between the glass and frame

Comment: Not the glass, but the whole window to rough opening(stud wall) should be about at least 1/8 to 1/4 minimum.  Think a 1/2 inch is close to normal, allows adjustment and house movement.